# Custom ConfigurationElementCollection Throw TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, app-config

I'm trying to make a Custom `ConfigurationSection` with `ConfigurationElementCollection`.
But when i use it throw a `ConfigurationErrorsException` with 2 detail exception`TargetInvocationException` And `MissingMethodException`

I console some message in the Constructor, result is just "new AssembySettingSection".
Exception throw at AssembySettingSection base["settings"].

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="AssembySetting" type="IngoWinService.AssembySettingSection, IngoWinService"/>
  </configSections>
  <AssembySetting>
    <settings>
      <add name="IngoWinService.Haier.Service" assemby="IngoWinService.Haier" />
    </settings>
  </AssembySetting>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Section Code(Post others when need)

```
public class AssembySettingSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    public AssembySettingSection()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("new AssembySettingSection");
    }
    [ConfigurationProperty("settings", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(AssembySettingCollection))]
    public ConfigurationElementCollection Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return base["settings"] as AssembySettingCollection;//Throw Exception
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I used the wrong element type in the problem. Anyway, answering this for other users.

The problem is fixed.

```
public class AssembySettingSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    public AssembySettingSection()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("new AssembySettingSection");
    }
    [ConfigurationProperty("settings", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(AssembySettingElement))]//Changed AssembySettingCollection to AssembySettingElement
    public AssembySettingCollection Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return base["settings"] as AssembySettingCollection;
        }
    }

}
```